# Change image on mobile and tablet (Semplice theme)

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am using Semplice Theme to build my portfolio and have encountered a challenge. I would like to learn how to change a image on a smaller device - both Mobile and tablet. I am new when it comes to coding.

I have searched for an answer here on stackoverflow but got confused of the answers because the code/solution i found are different from the image code on Semplice.

Good to know. In the Semplice theme you can write a custom code before entering the content editor on the page you are editing, and it looks like this.

[image: Custom css]

**The img code i have looks like this:**

```
<img class="live-image" src="/02_shirt.png" alt="02_shirt" style="">
<img class="live-image" src="/03_bag.png" alt="03_bag" style="">
```

**and they are both in a separate div:**

```
<div class="column-image column-img-full left">
<div class="column-image column-img-full right">
```

Best,
Ray

Answer (score 2):

take a look at [media_queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) This what you are looking for

Just add this little custom CSS to ‘Semplice’ → ‘Advanced Styling’ → ‘Custom CSS & JS’ → ‘Custom CSS’

**choose whatever screen you want here**

place you class or id selector in between these media queries.

```
/* Custom, iPhone Retina */
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
@media only screen and (min-width: 544px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {

}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

}
```

and to hide an element use :

```
display:none;
```

and to show use:

```
display:block;
```

you can go like:

```css
    .hidden-xs-sm-md{
        display:none;
    }
    
      /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
        @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
        
    
          .hidden-xs-sm-md{
               display:block;
           }
        
        }
```

```html
   
    <img class="live-image hidden-xs-sm-md" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/24/Blue_Tshirt.jpg/220px-Blue_Tshirt.jpg" alt="02_shirt" style=""> 
    <img class="live-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/24/Blue_Tshirt.jpg/220px-Blue_Tshirt.jpg" alt="03_bag" style="">
```

**hidden-xs-sm-md** this class will hide the element for mobile and tablet but the element will be visible for laptop and desktop

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

I have been trying to copy the example you provided into the semplice - custom css- but the image (02_shirt) wont disappear. And I cant figure out which of the code above will replace 02_shirt.png?

Comment: take a look above you will see only one image image and when you click on full screen you will see two images

Comment: you will see one image by default because the size of frame represents tablet screen size and you will see 2 image on full screen because it represent a laptop or desktop screen size. I hope it is clear now